# Is it possible to let a user modify elements of an html file using javascript/php or something similar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-io

Say a user was viewing a webpage with some content like

```
<div>some text</div>
```

Is there any way to allow them to change the contents to

```
<div>new text</div>
```

and commit these changes to the html file permanently/dynamically(all without making use of a database to store the contents of the div)?

Below is somewhat an example of what I want to do(click the text area to edit it):
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

However the above plugin uses an sqlite database to save changes/store info rather then modifying the actual html file.

I know this would be possible by using some scripting language like python/perl, but is there any simpler way to do this (like with php/javascript/jquery etc.)

***EDIT: 
Also, reason I don't want to use a database is so that I can move all my files to any web server without having to set anything up. Also even something like sql lite might work out messy for what I am doing.

Comment: The HTML file is stored on the server. JavaScript runs in the browser of the client and can send request to the server. Therefore it is not possible to modify the file on the server. You need some Webserver, that interprets the request and modifies the file.

Comment: True, but I would normally password protect editable features, so only a logged in user would be able to make changes.

Comment: Certainly possible with a server side language like php

Comment: PHP _IS_ a scripting language (like python/perl).

Comment: I was initially thinking of using file handling in php to rewrite the entire html file with the new changes, but I was wondering if I could do something simpler to just modify div contents...

Comment: You could cobble something together with class names and regex to just change certain elements,  but I doubt it would be any simpler than standard database system

Comment: Wouldn't what you are asking going to create race conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will be suitable for your purposes to use some kind of wysiwyg editors. Some of them appears only on dbl click on the text, so, user can dbl click text, edit, and then for example by pressing button "save" create an ajax request to your server.

---

[This is](http://orthes.github.io/medium-editor-insert-plugin/) the example of text editor.

Comment: Thanks, this actually got me on the right track for what I want to do.  I found a wysiwyg js plugin called nicEditor which allows me to save edits(and styles) using ajax to a database or retrieve the html value of edits using js (which I might do if I want to hardcode inline edits to a new html file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can load a file dynamically with php.  Then whenever you want to save post the body DOM back to your server and overwrite the existing file.  This is typically considered extremely poor practice though.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
       function SaveBody() {
           var body = document.getElementById("divtoSave");
           var f = document.createElement("form");
           f.setAttribute('method',"post");
           f.setAttribute('action',"save.php");
           var b = document.createElement("input");
           b.type = "text";
           b.name = "body";
           b.id = body;
           f.appendChild(b);
           f.submit();
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divToSave">
<?php 
include "otherfile.txt";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

save.php

```
<?php

     file_put_contents("otherfile.txt", $_POST['body']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need each user to be able to see his/her own changes, you can use HTML5 storage APIs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

In order for a user to make changes to a page and then have that change visible to other users, there will need to be server involved. You could use PHP (or a good language) to write to an HTML file directly, but you may run into problems if multiple users want to edit at once. That's where a database comes in handy.

If you're looking for a simple solution, then one option may be to use someone else's server. For example, GitHub exposes APIs for editing files. For an example of how you could use this sort of thing, see the prose.io open source content editor: http://prose.io/#about and https://github.com/prose/prose. It's written using entirely client-side technology.

Comment: Only a single user would have access to making changes, but these would be to publicly visible to everyone. I'm thinking about storing the files on a standard webserver , so using php seems ok. Is there any way to just dynamically select a div id and edit its contents without rewriting the whole file?

Comment: @Lin457. A div won't correspond to any individual file on your filesystem unless you set things up in a really kooky way. If you want functionality like they show off in your link (Jeditable), just use a database. Jedit is agnostic as to how the server stores the data. It sounds like you don't like SQL, so why not use MongoDB? It basically stores data in JSON format and you could do all the server-side logic in <20 lines of code. If you use Node, you've got an all-JS solution, which will be very familiar if you mostly client-side work.